# Link enumerate item to subsection

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate

I have an `enumerate` like this

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item this is item 1 in \ref{SectionName1}
\item this is item 2 in \ref{SectionName2}
\end{enumerate}

\section{AAA}
\label{SectionName1}
text
\section{BBB}
\label{SectionName2}
text
```

This generates something like this:

> 1 this is item 1 in 1.2
>      2 this is item 2 in 1.3
>
> AAA
>      text
>      BBB
>      text

The links in the enumerate are 1.2 and 1.3. 
But what I want to do is something different. I want to make the entire item into a link to a section instead of just the section's number. For example:

> 1 this is item 1
>   2 this is item 2
>
> AAA
>   text
>   BBB
>   text

I want that whenever I click on the item's text ("this is item 1" and "this is item 2") to redirect me to the section.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Are you after producing a table of contents?

Comment: @HarishKumar yes .. I already found an answer but thank you very much for your interest in the question .... the answer is below and it's already marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have loaded `hyperref`. Then `\hyperref` helps. It supports an optional argument with a label name:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \hyperref[SectionName1]{this is item 1}
\item \hyperref[SectionName2]{this is item 2}
\end{enumerate}

\section{AAA}
\label{SectionName1}
text
\section{BBB}
\label{SectionName2}
text
```